# Servlet Error : Requested Resource not available

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I want to deploy and execute web app manually.

### Directory Structure :

### webapps > Simple Program (Contains Servlet & JSP Files) > WEB_INF (Contain web.xml) > classes (Contains Classes)

**Servlet : ServletClassCalled**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

@WebServlet("/ServletClassCalled")
public class ServletClassCalled extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String chkValues[] = request.getParameterValues("chk1");
        pw.write("Success");
        pw.write(username);
        pw.write("Chk Val 1 "+chkValues[0]+" Chk Val 2 "+chkValues[1]);
    }
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
        out.print(paramName);
        String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
        out.println(paramValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**JSP : index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple App</h1>
<form method="get" action="ServletClassCalled">
    User Name : <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
    Hobbies: <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="Coding" /> Coding <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="Sleeping" /> Sleeping<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<hr/>
<form method="post" action="ServletClassCalled">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Deployment Descriptor : web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

    <!-- Define servlets that are included in the example application -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ServletClassCalled</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>ServletClassCalled</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletClassCalled</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletClassCalled</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>GetHeader</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>GetHeader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetHeader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetHeader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

As i have listed index file in welcome list so it displayed correctly but when i try to submit form it is showing error.

[image: Servlet Error]

Comment: Check the URL where the action is being posted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : http://localhost:8080/SimpleProg/ServletClassCalled on form being submitted. am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Ok, then please post the stacktrace or another error message you get. Also, if you're working with Servlet 3.0, you don't need to declare the servlet twice: use annotations or declare it in the web.xml with a different name.

Comment: What is the package of the servlet class? Where is its class file located in the deloyed webapp structure? Why do you use web.xml AND annotations to define and map the servlet (you could remove the web.xml file completely)

Comment: @JBNizet : I have given the directory structure above in the question.

Comment: @JBNizet : web.xml removed. Error still remains

Comment: I guess that your class must be inside a package. Try this and notify us.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : i didn't get what you are trying to say...

Comment: Create a (Java) package in your project, add the class to that package, rebuild and redeploy the application, test this one more time.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza :  tried it. yet not working. i have made a package src. Move Servlet files in that package. change servlet path to src.ServletClassCalled in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to close my  tag in web.xml. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the updated Servlet version 3.0
It provides features that will internally map the servlet using the package

- javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

Also the auto-generated code for the servlet path is generated

- @WebServlet("/ServletClassCalled")

So, there is no need to write mapping of the servlet in web.xml file if you are using the servlet 3.0